# VueJS 2 and Vee-Validate

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

after playing around with the docs etc.. i got some problems with a  .. I'll paste the code below.

```
<!-- Subject FIeld -->
  <div class="field">
    <p :class="{ 'control': true, 'has-icon': true, 'has-icon-right': true }">
      <input name="onderwerp" v-validate="'required|alpha|min:3'" :class="{'input': true, 'is-danger': fields.failed('onderwerp'), 'is-success': fields.passed('onderwerp') }" type="text"  id="onderwerp" placeholder="Onderwerp">
      <span v-show="fields.failed('onderwerp') || fields.passed('onderwerp')" class="icon is-small">
        <i :class="{ 'fa': true, 'fa-warning': fields.failed('onderwerp'), 'fa-check': fields.passed('onderwerp') }"></i>
      </span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <!-- Question Field -->
      <div class="field">
        <!--{{--<label class="label">Vraag</label>--}}-->
    <p :class="{ 'control': true, 'has-icon': true, 'has-icon-right': true }">
      <textarea v-validate="'required|alpha|min:10'" :class="{'textarea': true, 'is-danger': errors.has('vraag') }" name="vraag" id="vraag" placeholder="Vraag"></textarea>
      <span v-show="errors.has('vraag')" class="icon is-small"><i class="fa fa-warning"></i></span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <!--test Field-->
  <div class="field">
    <!--{{--<label class="label">Vraag</label>--}}-->
    <p :class="{ 'control': true, 'has-icon': true, 'has-icon-right': true }">
      <textarea name="testfield" v-validate="'required|alpha|min:10'" :class="{'textarea': true, 'is-danger': fields.failed('testfield'), 'is-success': fields.passed('testfield') }" id="testfield" placeholder="Vraag"></textarea>
      <span v-show="fields.failed('testfield') || fields.passed('testfield')" class="icon is-small">
        <i :class="{ 'fa': true, 'fa-warning': fields.failed('testfield'), 'fa-check': fields.passed('testfield') }"></i>
      </span>
    </p>
  </div>
```

Script code:

```
    <script>
  export default {
    name: 'Contact-Form',
    data: () => ({
      name: '',
      telefoon: '',
      email: '',
      onderwerp: '',
      testfield: '',
      vraag: ''
    })
  };
</script>
```

Everything works, except when i remove the question field part. Then the whole form stops working as intended.

anyone got any idea this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide more info?
[Fiddle without question field](https://jsfiddle.net/z11fe07p/1093/) seems to work fine. Do you get errors in console?

Comment: Yea, that works, and testfield works aswell with the checkmark. but when i remove the question field it doesnt. 

No error at all. the checks just don't work. :<

Comment: Just edit the fiddle from above so I can understand

Comment: I did, when you remove the Question field part... it doesnt work anymore..

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

you have to show a error, can make it hidden or whatever but it needs to render.

```
<span v-show="fields.failed('fieldname')" class="hidden">{{ errors.first('fieldname') }}</span>
```

This will fix the form checks. ;)